# Run 30 jar from batch and save the output result for each jar

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

Hi i have a question about running several jar files in the same folder by batch file.
I need to create a loop and read all the jar files name, and run them all, and create output for all jars.
like this code:

```
cls
cd\ 
cd C:\java\
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;
cls

javac -jar "here come the name from the folder"

jarname < input1+"the name of the jar".txt > output1+"the name of the jar".txt
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what?do u need to run all jar files in a folder one by one and save the output ?

Comment: Yes, but save outputs for each jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
for %%j in (*.jar) do (
java -jar "%%j" < "input%%~nj.txt" > "output%%~nj.txt"
)
```

Comment: You may want to use `"input1%%~nj.txt"` and `"output1%%~nj.txt"`. The `~n` modifier expands to the base name only, without the extension.